# Eclipse RCP: Updating an MVC Model from Background Job

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, eclipse-rcp, jobs

I have an Eclipse RCP application with a ViewPart that is based on the MVC paradigm.

The MVC view (a Composite) registers itself as a listener to the MVC model, and updates its widgets when the model changes.

I also have a background job (using the Eclipse Job Framework) which fetches some data from a server, and then updates the model. In my simple implementation this leads to a SWTException "Invalid thread access" because after updating the model the listener in the view is now called from the non-UI thread.

What would be the recommended way to solve this?

### Current way:

Currently the Job code looks like this (leads to exception after the `viewModel.setData(data)` call):

```
public class MyJob extends Job {

    private MyViewModel viewModel;

    public MyJob(MyViewModel viewModel) {
        super("MyJob");
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        MyData data = fetchDataFromServer();

        viewModel.setData(data);

        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
}
```

### Possible solutions:

- Updating the model from the Job via `asyncExec()`. In my MyJob#run method:

  ```
  MyData data = fetchDataFromServer();

  Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          viewModel.setData(data);
      }
  });

  return Status.OK_STATUS;
  ```

  This seems slightly weird because the model itself should not have anything to do with the UI, and so calling it via the UI thread mechanism feels wrong.
- Using `asyncExec()` in the listener in the view:

  ```
  public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
      Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              reloadWidgets();
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  This seems also strange because the view is an integral part of the UI and so should not have to update its widgets in this "roundabout" way.

Would there be any better way to solve the issue?

Comment: You could also use `asyncExec` in the method in the model which fires the 'update' listener events. You will have to use `asyncExec` (or `syncExec`) somewhere.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the comment, that sounds indeed like a good possible way. I have to check whether this is possible in our MVC implementation; the notification mechanism was already in place when I took over the code, which is why I forgot about this possibility. Also the use of `syncExec`might suit me even better than `asyncExec` here as it mimics more the normal call of a method.